# Unexpected results moving files between folders

Tags: java

I am trying to add a very simple feature to a Java program. The feature I want to add simply moves all the files from two folders to a third "archive" folder. The code is simple and I understand it 100% the problem is only one of the folder's contents is being moved. I have went over the code with a fine-tooth comb and tried repasting the directory several times, nothing seems to work. If anyone could help me figure out why my 2nd folder's contents aren't being moved I would REALLY appreciate it.

FYI in order to test this code you need to add a couple folders to "My Documents".
"Pain008Files", "Camt54 Files" and "archive". Also you just need to add some type of text file to the Pain008 and Camt5 folder, it can only have a random letter just something that can be moved.

At runtime the Pain008Files folder correctly has all it's files moved to the archive folder. The Camt54 Files does not. The only problem I can think of is that perhaps the space in the Camt54 Files name is causing a problem but that doesn't make sense so I thought I would hold off on changing it till I get some help. Thanks in advance!

Main Class

```
package fileHandling;

public class moveTestMain 

{

    public static void main(String args[]){

        GetUser gUser = new GetUser();
        gUser.getUser();

        MoveFiles mFiles = new MoveFiles();
        mFiles.moveCamtFiles();
        mFiles.movePainFiles();

    }

}
```

Gets the user-name class

```
package fileHandling;

public class GetUser

{

    public static String currentUser = null;

    public void getUser(){

        currentUser = System.getProperty("user.name");

    }

}
```

Move the files class

```
package fileHandling;

import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MoveFiles 

{

    public static ArrayList<File> pain008Files;
    public static ArrayList<File> camt54Files;;

    public void movePainFiles(){

        File pain008File = new File("C:\\Users\\"+GetUser.currentUser+"\\Documents\\Pain008Files");
        pain008Files = new ArrayList<File>(Arrays.asList(pain008File.listFiles()));

        System.out.println(pain008Files);

        for(int i = 0; i < pain008Files.size(); i++){

            System.out.println("Test");

            int cutAmount = GetUser.currentUser.length();

            String fileName = pain008Files.get(i).toString().substring(33+cutAmount,pain008Files.get(i).toString().length());

            System.out.println(fileName);


            System.out.println(pain008Files.get(i).toString());

            pain008Files.get(i).renameTo(new File("C:\\Users\\"+GetUser.currentUser+"\\Documents\\archive\\"+
            "archivedPain_"+fileName));


    }

    }

    public void moveCamtFiles(){

        File camt54File = new File("C:\\Users\\"+GetUser.currentUser+"\\Documents\\Camt54 Files");

        camt54Files = new ArrayList<File>(Arrays.asList(camt54File.listFiles()));

        for(int i = 0; i < camt54Files.size(); i++){

            int cutAmount = GetUser.currentUser.length();

            String fileName = camt54Files.get(i).toString().substring(32+cutAmount,camt54Files.get(i).toString().length());

            camt54Files.get(i).renameTo(new File("C:\\Users\\"+GetUser.currentUser+"\\Documents\\archive\\"+
            "archivedCamt_"+fileName));

        }

    }
```

Comment: Try replacing the space: `Camt54%32%Files`. See if that helps

Comment: What happens when you step through the code?  Are you getting any errors?  One thing that's different is the presence of a space in one directory name, which could be causing issues.

Comment: You might get rid of the problems having a look at [Files.move](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-). Then you don't need to manually craft the destination file name with a substring construct.

Comment: I'll try that Roel. @Marshall I am having trouble stepping through this code. I've had a problem with the debugger related to the Apache POI that I'm using that keeps me from debugging but that's another issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SHORT ANSWER:**

Your code has some typo errors in routes or somewhere...

---

**LONG ANSWER:**

I adapted it to local testing in my computer and works fine.

```
public void movePainFiles() {

    File pain008File = new File("C:\\tmp\\pain");
    pain008Files = new ArrayList<File>(Arrays.asList(pain008File.listFiles()));

    System.out.println(pain008Files);

    for (int i = 0; i < pain008Files.size(); i++) {

        System.out.println(pain008Files.get(i).toString());

        pain008Files.get(i).renameTo(new File("C:\\tmp\\archive\\" + "archivedPain_" + pain008Files.get(i).getName()));

    }

}

public void moveCamtFiles() {

    File camt54File = new File("C:\\tmp\\camt");

    camt54Files = new ArrayList<File>(Arrays.asList(camt54File.listFiles()));

    for (int i = 0; i < camt54Files.size(); i++) {

        System.out.println(camt54Files.get(i).toString());
        camt54Files.get(i).renameTo(new File("C:\\tmp\\archive\\" + "archivedCamt_" + camt54Files.get(i).getName()));

    }

}
```

OUTPUT:

```
C:\tmp\camt\xxx.pdf
C:\tmp\camt\yyy.pdf
C:\tmp\camt\zzz.pdf
[C:\tmp\pain\Q37024973.txt, C:\tmp\pain\Q37545784.txt]
C:\tmp\pain\Q37024973.txt
C:\tmp\pain\Q37545784.txt
```

Comment: Although you didn't exactly explicitly answer my question the comments and your example helped me figure it out. It was in fact the space that was causing the problem. I tried the %32% but got a null pointer so I tried again with no spaces like you did and it worked fine. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Why are you create a list from the array returned by `listFiles()` and then again create a list from that list? `pain008Files` could even stay as `File[]`.

Comment: I am not OP does... I didnt start revising code as long as worked